# Oracle SQL, how to get a value from outside of a cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, database-cursor

I am currently trying to find a way to group my reservations by the type of reservation they are and my template cannot support such actions so I have to do it using SQL. THe problem is for my template to work I have to use sql cursors and after doing tests and researches I cannot figure out a way to do it.

My SQL query :

```
select cursor(
    -- selecting infos for client (deleted to make it easier to read)
    cursor (
        select OBJETS_FAMILLES.LIBELLE as FAMILLE_OBJET, -- WIll be used as a reservation category to regroup reservations that falls under this category
        cursor (
            -- Selecting infos for the reservation
            select RESERVATIONS.LIBELLE as LIBELLE_RESERVATION,
            OBJETS_FAMILLES.LIBELLE as TYPE_RESERVATION, -- Using this info to compare it with FAMILLE_OBJET
            to_char(RESERVATIONS.DATE_DEBUT,'dd.mm.yyyy') as DATE_RESERVATION,
            RESERVATIONS.NUMERO as NUM_RES,
            OBJETS.LIBELLE as LIBELLE,
            LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.QTE_RESERVE as QTE_RESERVE,
            LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.RABAIS_FRANCS as RABAIS_FRANCS,
            LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.PRIX_UNITAIRE_FORCE as PRIX_UNITAIRE,
            LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.DUPL_MONTANT as MONTANT_TTC,
            OBJETS.COMPLEMENT as COMPLEMENT,
            UNITES.LIBELLE as UNITE
            from COMMUNES COMMUNES,
            TARIFS TARIFS,
            OBJETS_FAMILLES OBJETS_FAMILLES,
            OBJETS OBJETS,
            RESERVATIONS RESERVATIONS,
            LIGNES_RESERVATIONS LIGNES_RESERVATIONS,
            POLITESSES POLITESSES,
            CLIENTS CLIENTS,
            UNITES UNITES
            where LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.OBJ_NUMERO=OBJETS.NUMERO
            and LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.OBJ_SOCIETES_ID=OBJETS.SOCIETES_ID
            and RESERVATIONS.CLI_NUMERO=CLIENTS.NUMERO
            and RESERVATIONS.CLI_SOCIETES_ID=CLIENTS.SOCIETES_ID
            and OBJETS.OBJ_FAM_NUMERO=OBJETS_FAMILLES.NUMERO
            and OBJETS.OBJ_FAM_SOCIETES_ID=OBJETS_FAMILLES.SOCIETES_ID
            and LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.RES_NUMERO=RESERVATIONS.NUMERO
            and LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.RES_SOCIETES_ID=RESERVATIONS.SOCIETES_ID
            and CLIENTS.COM_NUMERO=COMMUNES.NUMERO
            and CLIENTS.COM_SOCIETES_ID=COMMUNES.SOCIETES_ID
            and LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.TRF_NUMERODEP=TARIFS.NUMERODEP
            and LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.TRF_SOCIETES_ID=TARIFS.SOCIETES_ID
            and LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.TRF_OBJ_NUMERO=TARIFS.OBJ_NUMERO
            and TARIFS.UNI_NUMERO=UNITES.NUMERO
            and TARIFS.UNI_SOCIETES_ID=UNITES.SOCIETES_ID
            and RESERVATIONS.SOCIETES_ID = 5
            and CLIENTS.POL_NUMERO=POLITESSES.NUMERO
            and CLIENTS.POL_SOCIETES_ID=POLITESSES.SOCIETES_ID
            and LIGNES_RESERVATIONS.res_numero in (select numero from reservations where numero = 93688 or res_parent = 93688)
            -- Here should be a condition comparing if TYPE_RESERVATION and FAMILLE_OBJET have the same value
        ) as "reservation_groupee"
        from OBJETS_FAMILLES OBJETS_FAMILLES
    ) as "reservation"
) as "client" from dual
```

What I need to do is to in my cursor "reservation_groupee" I need to find a way to get the value from it's parent cursor "reservation" and to only select the datas where their value "TYPE_RESERVATION" is the same as "FAMILLE_OBJET".

Comment: Please provide [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I don't think that every of those 100 columns has a meaning to describe the issue. Also please clarify what you  imply by stating  "I **have to** use cursors".

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for a **MINIMAL** set of tables; the `INSERT` statements for a **MINIMAL** set of data; a **MINIMAL** query (that only uses a few columns and tables) that demonstrates the problem; an English description (not code) of the problem; the issues/errors with your query; and the expected output. You are not going to get good answers if you present us with a huge query, without any way of replicating the tables and a single sentence description that does not mean much to us if we do not have your domain knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I can't follow your enormous query, but the principle is simply to *correlate* the inner query with its parent, like this example:

```
select dname
     , cursor (select ename from emp e
               where e.deptno = e.deptno) -- correlation
  from dept d;
```

Comment: I just edited to try to make it easier to understand. Thanks for taking the time to read it